# Flutter Navigation Issue in going back to previous screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have 3 screens such as Login, HomeScreen, ProdcutScreen. From HomeScreen I route to ProductScreen like

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ProductScreen(img: Image(AssetImage('assets/1.png)), brand: 'ZARA')));
}
```

In the Product Screen if I press the arrow from the appBar its going back to HomeScreen. But When I press the device's back button its redirecting to the LoginScreen instead of HomeScreen. I tried looking for the solution in SO. I tried implementing WillPopScope but still the same. can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.  and how to overcome this isse. TIA

Comment: Check if this helps: https://gist.github.com/b-cancel/0ca372017a25f0c120b14dfca3591aa5

Comment: I think the problem is with the return statement just before ProductScreen try removing that

Comment: Sorry mistakenly I typed

Comment: @Mobina So you are asking me to disable the back button?

Comment: No I'm telling you to re-program it if you didn't find any better solution.

Comment: @LakshmiYogeshwaran are you trying this on a physical device or an emulator?

Comment: Please post the code about how you implemented `WillPopScope`

Comment: @JigarPatel M trying this on a physical device

Comment: @LakshmiYogeshwaran then if the back button on the device is a physical button, it is also possible that the button is faulty and is registering the tap twice. To verify if this is the case, you can try on another device or an emulator and see if the same thing happens.